# Drawing a SVG image on a Canvas in flutter, with flutter_svg

Tags: flutter, svg

I would like to be able to draw both SVG images and painted graphics (mostly lines between the SVG) on a Flutter Canvas. Currently, I am stuck at the step of being able to paint SVG on the Canvas.

I tried different approaches with flutter_svg. The most sensible one seems (to me) to be the following. But when I execute the code, the blue circle appears, but not the Svg image (which I already checked that it works with flutter_svg). It also seems that I have sometime some warnings regarding a null reference to a closure, when I hot reload the app.

```
class MyCanvas extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 9, 184);

    vg
        .loadPicture(const SvgAssetLoader("assets/Monogramme_dark.svg"), null)
        .then((picture) => picture.picture
            .toImage(50, 50)
            .then((image) => canvas.drawImage(image, Offset(100, 100), paint)));

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(50.0, 20.0), 10, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyCanvas oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: no no, no, you have to `loadPicture` outside and pass your `Picture` to your custom painter constructor so that you can simtply call `Canvad.drawPicture` (not `drawImage`) in `paint` method

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to lift all the call to loadPicture into an upward StatefulWidget, then draw (and redraw) as soon as the Picture is not null, but it still doesn't work: it doesn't report any exception nor error, but the picture itself doesn't draw.

Comment: are you sure your SVG is supported by `flutter_svg`? tried to display it via normal SVG widget?

Comment: Yes. It draws normally if I load it in the widget tree with SvgPicture.asset. But in the canvas I need to mix vector images (the svg files) with lines between them to draw a graph, this is why I didn't use the SvgPicture.

Comment: OK, thanks @pskink! The last version of my code was quite close to what you sent in your pastebin, but it lacked the ValueNotifier! I added it and now it works properly. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: actually `ValueNotifier` is not needed - you can also call `setState` and rebuild your stateful widget (and custom painter) - it will work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've written in my previous answer, there are different approaches for this, instead of using Canvas.

You can Define your working area as a rectangle, square, or whatever shape you prefer, and draw everything relative to that area.

For this, you can use the `Stack` and `Positioned` widgets to draw components on top of each other, and on specific locations. [Look at this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66236139/4605422)

You can also look at this tutorial on Medium [Dragging, zooming, and placing objects on indoor maps with Flutter](https://medium.com/@alexander.arendar/dragging-zooming-and-placing-object-on-indoor-map-with-flutter-67667ef415ec) which explains a similar system created with Canvas, where you can place objects and interact with them.

Don't forget that despite using Canvas, you can still take advantage of the SetState properties of Flutter, to track any items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I need to mix "classing" drawing and SVG on the same picture: to simplify, I need to draw a graph where nodes are images (in SVG format) and edges will be lines, drawn "classically".

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? 
Is it something like this? [Flutter point cloud](https://medium.com/@dengpan9610.wang/flutter-build-a-cloud-planet-6e5238720045)

Comment: Not exactly. I try to make a UI for an electrical circuit simulator (of some particular kind). So on one side, I have my engine answering to an API; and on the other side (UI) I want to draw some kind of electrical circuit, where the components are in SVG, and will be linked by Lines in order to show electrical connections. Once I have this working, I will animate the circuit with the data coming from the engine.

Comment: I've changed my answer, take a look at those links, maybe they are useful to you... Good luck. Start with a small example, and work from there.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. I can have my "line canvas" on the background to freely draw on it, and the SVG widget drawing is available. I will go this way!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    class MyCanvas extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 9, 184);
    final pictureInfo = await vg
        .loadPicture(const SvgAssetLoader("assets/Monogramme_dark.svg"), null);
    final image = await pictureInfo.picture.toImage(50, 50);
    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset(100, 100), paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(50.0, 20.0), 10, paint);
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyCanvas oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code but it throws an exception on the canvas.drawImage at start up : StateError (Bad state: A Dart object attempted to access a native peer, ...)

Comment: you need to move the canvas.drawImage().